# Plasma effects lost in Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, effects, kwin, plasma-5

I had some [crash reports](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347144) after trying to change virtual desks of windows by dragging. I realized it had to do with cube animations. And after trying some configurations, having new crashes and rebooting plasma effects seem to be dead, no matter the configuration is set.

How do I get back plasma effects?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try changing the compositor back to OpenGL in Sytemsettings -> Hardware -> Display and Monitor -> Compositor